# Domain of attraction of $\alpha$-stable distributions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I have been trying to understand why in Remark 2.4.1 c) of [these lecture notes](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.110/mitarbeiter/spodarev/publications/scripts/Stable_Distributions.pdf), $a_n$ can be chosen as $0$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$. So I have a distribution function $F$ given which satisfies $1-F(x)+F(-x)=x^{-\alpha}L(x)$ for $x>0$ where $L$ is slowly varying at infinity and I know that this implies that for an iid sequence of random variables $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $X_1\sim F$ there exist sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $b_n>0$ for all $n$ and
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{i=1}^n
X_i-a_n\overset{d}{\to}X\sim G
\end{align*}
for some $\alpha$-stable distribution function $G$. Furthermore the sequence $(b_n)$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(F(b_nx)-1)=c_1x^{-\alpha}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}nF(-b_nx)=c_2x^{-\alpha}$ for all $x>0$ for some $c_1,c_2\geq0$ with $c_1+c_2>0$. Theorem 2.1.3 of the lecture notes gives a possibility how the $a_n$ can be chosen. To show that $a_n$ can be chosen as $0$, it is sufficient to show that
\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{b_n}\int_{(-b_n,b_n)}x\text{d}F(x)
\end{align*}
converges as $n\to\infty$ (this should be $A_n(1)$ from Theorem 2.1.3). My approch is the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{b_n}\int_{(-b_n,b_n)}x\text{d}F(x)&=E\left\lbrack\frac{n}{b_n} X_11_{\{|X_1|<b_n\}}\right\rbrack\\&=\frac{n}{b_n}\left(\int_0^{\infty}P(X_1^+1_{\{|X_1|<b_n\}}>t)\text{d}t-\int_0^{\infty}P(X_1^-1_{\{|X_1|<b_n\}}>t)\text{d}t\right)\\
        &=\frac{n}{b_n}\left(\int_0^{\infty}1_{t<b_n}P(X_1\in(t,b_n))\text{d}t-\int_0^{\infty}1_{t<b_n}P(X_1\in(-b_n,-t))\text{d}t\right)
\end{align*}
Unfortunately I dont know how to show how to continue. Does anyone have an idea?